# Oracle outer join with filter condition on the second table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is there any condition under which the result sets will be different from the following two statements?

```
select  * from a,b where a.id = b.id and b.name = 'XYZ'
select  * from a,b where a.id =b.id(+) and b.name = 'XYZ'
```

I think in both cases it will bring the common rows from a and b where `b.name = 'XYZ'`. So `a.id = b.id(+)` has no meaning.

Comment: Please use the SQL-92 join syntax rather than the old SQL-86 "(+)" syntax, it's much easier to see and debug.

Comment: @Ollie: I wouldn't recommend this in general. Oracle still has some rare but nasty bugs with ANSI joins. And "much easier to see and debug" is just a point of view. I personally prefer the "old" style if the where clause is properly ordered and formatted.

Comment: @GWu, that's a big "if" you use. I totally disagree with you, feel free to post a link to the bugs but the common issues with the old SQL-86 syntax are well documented, hence the advice to go with SQL-92 (from Oracle themselves as well as others). We might have to agree to disagree though in this instance but I stand by my advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no condition under which the result sets will be different.

But your assumption "`a.id = b.id(+)` has no meaning" is not 100% correct. It *has* a meaning, because it defines the join, otherwise this would be a cartesian product of a and b with all rows from a and b.name = 'XYZ'.

What has no effect is the `(+)`, because the statement is "semantically" wrong. It makes no sense to outer join on id but to join on name.

Usually something like that is wanted:

```
select  * from a,b where a.id =b.id(+) and b.name(+) = 'XYZ';
```

Short example at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d19b4/15

Comment: will b.name(+) = 'XYZ' do anything? it seems the filter will not do filtering since we have the (+)

Comment: yes, see my example at sqlfiddle: you get _all_ lines from a and all lines from b with XZY

Comment: if i get all lines from b, then what is the point of putting any filter?we can write select * from a,b

Comment: all lines from b *with XZY*. select * from a,b will pull a cartesian product.