# oracle query :same table selected twice with different alias names but same where clause filter

Tags: oracle11g

I have a query like this which i am supposed to refactor:

```
SELECT *
  FROM a a1
      ,b common_alias
      ,b common_alias1
 WHERE a1.id = common_alias.id(+)
   AND a1.id = common_alias1.id(+)
   AND common_alias.name = 'XYZ'
   AND common_alias1.name = 'XYZ'
UNION
SELECT *
  FROM a a1
      ,b common_alias
      ,b common_alias1
 WHERE a1.id = common_alias.id(+)
   AND a1.id = common_alias1.id(+)
   AND common_alias.name = 'XYZ'
   AND common_alias1.name = 'PQR'
```

It seems to me that i can remove the first query completely. Is there any case where removing the first query will make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer join condition on `common_alias1.id` should be reviewed, it has no effect, as you don't outer join on `common_alias1.name` as well. See [Oracle outer join with filter condition on the second table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568425/oracle-outer-join-with-filter-condition-on-the-second-table/11573445#11573445).

But back to your question: no, you can't remove the first part, where would you get the XYZ|XYZ row? See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c7dfa/12 for an example.

But you can refactor to

```
SELECT a1.*,common_alias.name n1,common_alias1.name n2
  FROM a a1
      ,b common_alias
      ,b common_alias1
 WHERE a1.id = common_alias.id(+)
   AND a1.id = common_alias1.id(+)
   AND common_alias.name = 'XYZ'
   AND (common_alias1.name = 'XYZ' OR common_alias1.name = 'PQR')
;
```

Comment: thanks for going above and beyond with your explanation. Much appreciate it sir.

Comment: I guess i can also do: select * from a,(select * from b where b.name='XYZ') alias1,(select * from b where b.name='PQR') alias2 where a.id=alias1.id(+) and a.id=alias2.id(+)